# Case-sensitive Firebase queries

Tags: javascript, java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've made an app that allows users to have a username, however, say if the username  'Nathan' is taken the user can still have the username 'nathan' and I don't want that. I would like my username's to be not case-sensitive so if 'Nathan' is taken the the user can't have something like 'NatHan' or something like that.

Thanks for your time,

Nathan

Answer (score 0):

Save all usernames in lowercase too in another field. And check if exist in that field.There is no another option for now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what about if I cant to prevent them from having a username like this 'naTHan' ?